# Ignore WHERE clause only for a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
@ValCycle = 'Selected Cycle'

select * from cycletable where case
        cycle = when @ValCycle = 'Selected Cycle' Then @NCycle
            else cycle 
end
```

This is my query. The problem is when the value of @ValCycle is different than `'Selected Cycle'` then all the null values of the column cycle are ignored. I need all of them including null, blank, and any value.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Thats not actually valid SQL... maybe post your exact SQL.

Comment: You cannot check `NULL`s for equality. `NULL` is never equal to `NULL`; the expression `NULL = NULL` will always be false. That's why you lose rows in your result. A fitting solution partly depends on your `@NCycle` variable. Can that variable be `NULL` as well? If so, what would the desired behavior of the query be?

Answer (score 0):

You’ve got a bit of a syntax error so your query won’t run but I get the idea.

Edit: you’ve clarified where the values come from, and when valcycle = ‘selected cycle’ then use a value that was previously selected

```
select * 
from cycletable 
where 
     @ValCycle <> 'Selected Cycle' OR
     cycle = @NCycle
```

Note that you don’t say what value @ValCycle will have if a value is not selected; if it’s null then `<>` wont work; use IS NULL instead. It's also not clear whether @NCycle will ever have a NULL value and you'll be looking for the nulls in the table; if you are, you'll need

```
select * 
from cycletable 
where 
     @ValCycle <> 'Selected Cycle' OR
     (@NCycle IS NULL AND cycle IS NULL) OR
     cycle = @NCycle
```

You're aiming for a condition that is always true if the value of @ValCycle isn’t 'Selected Cycle'. Personally I'd have skipped it and made @NCycle either null (if I wanted all rows) or a value (if I wanted those values) and had `WHERE @NCycle IS NULL Or cycle = @NCycle` - single variable rather than two - unless having @NCycle of NULL is a valid value that you want to search for

Consider that this form may give better plans, and is more self documenting:

```
IF @ValCycle = ‘Selected Cycle’
  select * 
  from cycletable
  where 
     cycle =  @NCycle;
ELSE
  select * 
  from cycletable;
```

Extending queries with “optional parameters” style where clauses may pick a poor plan because the plan can be cached based on one set of parameters and a new set means the plan is suboptimal. Splitting them up into separate queries avoids this, though you may still encounter issues with any parameterized queries, if the distribution of values you seek is uneven

Comment: I think you meant `cycle = @NCycle`.

Comment: `Selected Cycle` is a value from code, it is a drop-down value. the value of @NCycle is taken beforehand from a SQL query.

Comment: @Andrew I promise I wrote what I meant; was aiming to simplify

Comment: @BruceWayne, I think this is what you need, although if that string is an order for the user, it should be "Select Cycle" instead. What this code does is return all rows when `ValCycle = 'Selected Cycle'`, or else just when `cycle = @ValCycle` (or `NCycle`).

Comment: @CaiusJard, I see, with your clarification it's ok. Although in that second code, `ValCycle <> 'Selected Cycle'` is unnecessary.

Comment: Beware `END IF` is from MySQL. I think MSSQL is smart enough and there shouldn't be performance differences. Anyway, I'd really prefer readability/maintainability over a few milliseconds.

Comment: Your first query's WHERE-expression could even be simplified to `@ValCycle <> 'Selected Cycle' OR @NCycle = cycle`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing `NULL` with `NULL` for equality will always be false.

I think that your issue cannot easily be solved using a `CASE` statement. I would convert it to the following SQL:

```
select * from cycletable where
  @ValCycle = 'Selected Cycle' or
  cycle = @NCycle OR (cycle IS NULL AND @NCycle IS NULL);
```

An `OR` in a `WHERE`-clause can be problematic for performance. Indexes will not be used in that case. To improve the query plans, you have two solutions:

1. Conversion to an `IF...ELSE` statement is already proposed in [Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664)'s answer. You only need to add the correct NULL checks to the WHERE-clause of the query in the IF-block. But that would introduce another OR, so the IF-block needs to be rearranged and extended:

```
IF @ValCycle <> 'Selected Cycle' OR @ValCycle IS NULL --I'm not sure if @ValCycle can be NULL...
  select * 
  from cycletable;
ELSE IF @NCycle IS NULL
  select * 
  from cycletable
  where cycle IS NULL;
ELSE
  select * 
  from cycletable
  where cycle = @NCycle;
```

2. Using `UNION`:

```
select * from cycletable where @ValCycle = 'Selected Cycle'
UNION
select * from cycletable where cycle = @NCycle
UNION
select * from cycletable where cycle IS NULL AND @NCycle IS NULL;
```

Comment: So you are saying that I cant do it inside a Case statement?

Comment: Do you want to do it inside a case statement? If you do, then you should have said. It would look like `where 
        COALESCE(cycle, 'x') = case when @ValCycle = 'Selected Cycle' Then @NCycle
            else COALESCE(cycle, 'x')` where 'x' is a value that never naturally occurs for `cycle`.. And that's *nasty*